# Rule of thumb for outliers in factor analysis by FactoMineR

Tags: r, factor-analysis, outliers

I preformed a factor analysis with the FactoMineR package (R) (FAMD function).
I would like to examine the results without outliers. What is the rule of thumb in this case?

I know one eazy way to detect outliers in Factominer is by examining high level of cos2. But what is the rule of thumb in this matter?

Comment: `examining high level of cos2` What is that? Can you please tell more about the method and where it is described?

Comment: I'm relyiing on the video lesson on youtube, by François Husson (which is one of the developers  of this method). in this viodeo he   shows how to select indidviduals with high cos2 in the purpose of eximining  (he uses the level of cos2=0.8 but I dont know what is the exact level).   cos2 explains the quality of representation  of the individual (or variable).

Comment: this is the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g5_hM93e8HM